# Error in formating the namenode in Hadoop single cluster node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I am trying to install and configure hadoop in the system Ubuntu 16.04, as per the guidelines of https://data-flair.training/blogs/installation-of-hadoop-3-x-on-ubuntu/

all the steps were run successfully, but while trying to run the command `hdfs namenode -format`, I get a message

Comment: Update question with correct error message (screenshot is correctly added)

Comment: Please don't add an image of a terminal. Copy the text output into the question itself. 1) The version you're downloading is an old alpha release 2) Hadoop 3 isn't "production ready", and Hadoop 2.7 is more commonly used by every other Hadoop vendor as for now 3) The official documentation should be used before any other guides

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your `bashrc` file. Just check your `variables` inside `bashrc`. Even I faced the same problem when I started with hadoop. Mention correct path for each and every variable and afterwards use `source ~/.bashrc` to commit the changes done to your `bashrc` file